# Perl Directory Analysis

Tags: perl

I have a Deep Directory Structure with the following format

```
/intf1/syst1/some1
/intf3/syst4/some111
/intf1/syst2/some2
/intf2/syst1/some1
/intf2/syst3/some9
/intf4/syst2/sdsds
```

Need the output, in the format"

```
        syst1   syst2   syst3   syst4
intf1   x       x       
intf2   x               x       
intf3                           x
intf4           x
```

How can I do this in Perl?

NOTE: intf1... intfn need to be sorted Alphanumerically, similarly syst1... systn the same

Answer (score 2):

1. Create hash of hashrefs to store the matrix you want (call it `%files`)
2. Create a hash to store the list of `syst` names (call it `%subdirs`. Should be a has instead of array to ensure uniqueness).
3. Use `glob()` to obtain a list of files
4. Use `File::Spec->splitpath()` to split each path in the list into directory components and filename.
5. Put value `1` into hash-of-hashrefs `%files` with keys determined by first and second directory components from previous step (e.g. `$files{$dir1}->{$dir2} = 1;`.

   Also, put value of `1` into the `%subdirs` hash for a subdirectory.
6. When done looping over the list of files, print results

   a. Run a loop over sorted list of keys for `%subdirs` hash. For each value, print that value followed by a space. Then at the end print newline.

   b. Run a loop over sorted list of keys for `%files` hash-of-hashrefs. For each key `$dir1`:

   i. Print the key value, followed by as many spaces as needed to ensure alignment. How to do that is left as excercise for the reader.

   ii. Run a loop over sorted list of keys for `%subdirs` hash. For each key `$dir2`:

   ```
     - Print an X if `$files{$dir1}->{$dfir2}` is true, and print 1 space otherwise.


     - print N spaces where N is a length of the directory `$dir2`
   ```

   iii. Print newline

Answer (score 0):

While @DVK's answer is the way I would go for a general problem of this sort, I am wondering if your instructor meant for you use arrays and regular expressions to solve this as you clearly have a matrix.

The code is terse and uncommented on purpose.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @matrix;

my ($i_max, $j_max) = (0, 0);

while ( my $path = <DATA> ) {
    next unless $path =~ m{/intf([0-9])/syst([0-9])/\w+};
    my ($i, $j) = map $_ - 1, $1, $2;
    $matrix[$i][$j] = 1;
    $i_max = $i if $i > $i_max;
    $j_max = $j if $j > $j_max;
}


print_row(['' => map "syst$_", 1 .. $j_max + 1]);

for my $i ( 0 .. $i_max ) {
    print_row([
        'intf' . ($i + 1), map {
            my $v = $matrix[$i][$_];
            defined($v) ? 'x' : '';
         } 0 .. $j_max
     ]);
}

sub print_row { print join("\t", @{ $_[0] }), "\n" }

__DATA__
/intf1/syst1/some1
/intf3/syst4/some111
/intf1/syst2/some2
/intf2/syst1/some1
/intf2/syst3/some9
/intf4/syst2/sdsds
```